# Should I unsubscribe from a MediaObserver subscription in flex-layout for Angular?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-flex-layout

In an Angular component, I'm using the following code to show different elements depending on screen resolution:

```
constructor(private mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {}

private mySubscription: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mySubscription = this.mediaObserver.asObservable().subscribe(() => {
        if (this.mediaObserver.isActive('gt-md')) {
          // Do some stuff...
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

My question is, do I need to unsubscribe from `mySubscription` in `ngOnDestroy()`, or does `MediaObserver` do this itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From example in README.md (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/MediaObserver)

```
export class MyDemo implements OnDestroy {
  watcher: Subscription;
  activeMediaQuery = '';

  constructor(mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
    this.watcher = mediaObserver.media$.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      this.activeMediaQuery = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : '';
      if ( change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
         this.loadMobileContent();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.watcher.unsubscribe();
  }

  loadMobileContent() { 
    // Do something special since the viewport is currently
    // using mobile display sizes
  }
}
```

Yes, you need to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()`.

Comment: Thanks for that - my only concern is that the documentation is pretty out of date, for example `media$` has been deprecated in favour of `asObservable()`, so I'm not sure I can rely on the README.  Is there any way in which to tell for sure?

Comment: You are right. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/core/media-observer/media-observer.ts I see nothing that handle unsubscribe for you there.